# How to save a table as an image but also preserve its quality? R

Tags: r

Looking for tips to save a table as an image with the quality seen in the RStudio Viewer. I've tried `save_kable` and `as_image` but both resulted in serious drops in quality.

Any other recommendations?

Code for reference:

```
library(htmlTable)
library(xtable)
library(kableExtra)
data(tli)
htmlTable(xtable(tli[1:10,),rnames=FALSE)%>%save_kable('table.png')`
```

Comment: What packages do these functions come from? Is there a way to increase the resolution of the image?

Comment: @camille htmlTable() is from htmlTable package, xtable() is from xtable, and save_kable() is from kableExtra. I've been looking at the save_kable documentation with no luck on raising quality of save, maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @user2554330 doesn't seem to have parameters for specifying quality. I made edits so the issue could reproduced.

Comment: @user2554330 you don't see a drop in quality between the htmlTable displayed in the viewer vs the one saved in your directory via save_kable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `save_kable` function has a `...` argument which passes variables to `webshot::webshot`.

From the webshot [README](https://github.com/wch/webshot), you can generate higher quality screenshots with the `zoom` option, e.g.,

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(magrittr)

kable(iris[1:10,]) %>%
  kable_styling() %>%
  save_kable(file = "table_1.png")

kable(iris[1:10,]) %>%
  kable_styling() %>%
  save_kable(file = "table_2.png",
             zoom = 1.5)
```